# how to make my mouse control program active on all windows

Tags: c#, mouse

I'm creating a program - using C#- that make use of usb connected device to control the mouse,
so for now I'm making a small windows form program that make use of keyboard for same purpose, but I got a problem that each time I click out the form my controls don't work any more, any suggestions?

I use user32.dll, VS2008

note: the device is EMOTIV EPOC

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you asking? You mean you want to control the mouse using another USB device? And that when you click outside the controls it doesn't work anymore? I don't think you can correct this since the winform loses focus as soon as you click out of it.

Comment: Maybe [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278237/keep-window-on-top-and-steal-focus-in-winforms). It sounds like a really similar issue.