# Why the explorer handle window trying bring it to the screen front doesn't do anything?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It's working with other handles windows.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
SetProcessWindow.BringToFront(processes[0].Id);
SetProcessWindow.CenterProcessWindow(processes[0].Id);
```

If the `processName` for example is `Taskmgr` it will bring to the front of the screen and will center it the Task Manager.

But if for example the `processName` is `explorer` (not internet explorer but explorer that in this case is a directory on the hard disk) it won't bring it to the front it will not do anything.

This is the `SetProcessWindow` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Automation
{
    class SetProcessWindow
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);

        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
        }

        private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
        private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

        public static void BringToFront(int processId)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;

            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }

        public static void CenterProcessWindow(int processId)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

            while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                process.Refresh();
                break;
            }

            IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;

            RECT rct;
            GetWindowRect(handle, out rct);
            Rectangle screen = Screen.FromHandle(handle).Bounds;
            Point pt = new Point(screen.Left + screen.Width / 2 - (rct.Right - rct.Left) / 2, screen.Top + screen.Height / 2 - (rct.Bottom - rct.Top) / 2);
            SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure maybe it doesn't bring some windows to the front since I changed in the project properties unchecked prefer 32-bit ?

Anyway some windows it bring to the front and some not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224673/focus-windows-explorer-from-c-sharp-app-in-task-bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132422/open-a-folder-using-process-start

Comment: Explorer creates *many* windows.  When you use MainWindowHandle then you usually get the taskbar.  Bringing it into the foreground could be useful, not very likely that's what you actually want.  Always use the Spy++ utility to get insight.  The ShellWindows COM object allows iterating the kind of window you are looking for.

Comment: My idea is realy to allow the user to bring to the front only applications. Like Skype like taskbar and this are working. The rest I will work on it later. I think what I wanted in general is working. The main idea was to do it with Elgato hd game capture software and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the same problem with handle creation you had inside your `CenterProcessWindow` method. Try adding this piece of code to your `BringToFront` method aswell.

```
while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    process.Refresh();
```

before this line : `IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;`. Also, you don't need `break;` inside that while loop. If you place break there it will go out of your while loop even if `MainWindoWHandle` is still `IntPtr.Zero`. The way you wrote it is the same as this:

```
if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    process.Refresh();
```

If it's `IntPtr.Zero`, refresh and continue, you're willing to wait for it to get some value, therefore while loop.