# Using Secondary USB Keyboard in .net

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0

I want to read data stream or a key stroke from a secondary USB keyboard to my .net windows application only. The keystrokes should be blocked in all other applications such as word,excel etc.. Is that Possible with .Net Windows application?

Obviously the master keyboard is also connected in the computer. The other application can get the keystrokes from this keyboard.
This .Net application should only capture the keystroke of secondary keyboard?
If somebody have any idea please help...

Thanks for your help in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it is not easy to block the keypresses of the second keyboard going to other applications, it is possible to know in your own application where the keypress originated and handle accordingly.  I asked a similar question several years ago, see the response to it:

[Multiple keyboards and low-level hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91234/multiple-keyboards-and-low-level-hooks)