# Detecting which key on the keyboard was pressed.with multiple keyboards present

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

The computer I have has two USB keyboards. Pushing a key on either keyboard will register a key press event. My question is, is there a way to determine which keyboard the key press came from using C#/Winforms?

Comment: Do these not help?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/92946/88217


http://stackoverflow.com/a/589326/88217

Comment: None of these links help. One talks just about scanners, not keyboards. Another link posted above does have a solution that I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the pastebin link is no longer valid