# Detect which USB device generated input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have 2 keyboards and I want to know if it's possible to know which keyboard generated an input event in Windows (using WINAPI)?

Comment: I removed the Qt tag, there's no cross platform way, I think, so Qt won't have it. Retagged it with winapi instead. Hope it's not a problem. Also see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56361/how-do-i-read-input-from-multiple-keyboards-mice-on-one-computer

Comment: @sashoalm That's the whole point of Qt... writing OS-independant code...

Comment: A long time ago I had some success with this project (it uses low level WinAPI calls): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

Comment: @alexandernst Yes, but there is no way to do that in Qt. You can only do it in winapi. If you ask "How do I do that in Qt" the answer is "You can't", which won't be very useful.

Comment: @sashoalm Ah, I see what you mean

Comment: @paul Is there a C++ port of that library? Or maybe a possibility to use it from C++? IMHO C# is a horrible language and I really don't want to do the entire project with it...

Comment: If it's using winapi then you can rewrite it in C++ of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to distinguish Multiple Keyboards in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3060512/292432)  Also [Multiple keyboards and low-level hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/91234/292432).  And many more.

Comment: @alexandernst the code is just a very simple wrapper that makes calls to WinAPI, so it should be possible to just implement that same wrapper (with the same calls) in c++

Comment: @sashoalm Won't `nativeEventFilter` help me here?

Comment: @alexandernst Sure, but it's ultimately not Qt, but Winapi - that's why there's native in the name. You will still use the native Winapi functions to deal with the events. Ultimately, your question is Winapi-specific, not Qt-specific.

Comment: @sashoalm Do you happen to have any links to an example how to filter the messages received in `nativeEventFilter`? To what should I cast the `msg` parameter?

Comment: @alexander: Remy's answer provides all the information you are asking for. Whether you place the code in Qt's `nativeEventFilter` or a pure Windows API application's window procedure makes no difference. And since you were confused about the Windows API's interface: All services are provided through an interface callable from C; it does not offer a .NET interface (although a wrapper is trivially easy to implement).

Answer (score 15):

Windows has a [RAW Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) that can be used to monitor events from keyboards, mice, and HIDs (joysticks, etc) without using low-level hooks.

Use [`GetRawInputDeviceList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645598.aspx) and [`GetRawInputDeviceInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597.aspx) to discover which keyboard devices are connected to the system.

Use [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600.aspx) to register for events from the desired keyboard devices.

You will receive a [`WM_INPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) message whenever an input event occurs on a registered device.  It will tell you which device sent it.

There is also a [`WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645591.aspx) message to notify you when devices are added and removed.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a valid and correct answer for the question asked. Microsoft introduced the RAW Input API specifically to allow apps to monitor events from multiple hardwares (with an emphasis on keyboards and mice, but any HID-compatible device will also work, such as joysticks) without having to use low-level hooks.

Comment: I'd guess the downvote was, because you didn't provide a Qt-solution. Since Qt does not offer services to implement the requested functionality it may be a good idea to explicitly state this in your answer. At any rate, shooting the messenger is never a wise idea.

Comment: @IInspectable: when I posted my answer, there was no mention of Qt in the question, and still isn't. Any reference to Qt was removed 2 hours before I posted.